# inconsistent string to int error and response

Tags: python

I've made a simple program where the users adds as many numbers as they would like then type 'exit' to stop it and print the total but sometimes it says the converting the string to int fails, and sometimes it does convert but then it has the wrong out put e.g I type 1 + 1 but it prints 1

```
def addition():
    x = 0
    y = 1
    total = 0

    while x < y:
        total += int(input())

        if input() == "exit":
            x += 1

    print(total)

addition()
```

I have tryed converting it to a float then to an int but still has inconsistency, I did start learning python today and am finding the syntax hard coming from c++ / c# / Java so please go easy on the errors

Comment: Have you tried to use raw_input instead of input ?

Comment: i can't use raw_input as i'm using python 3

Comment: @Tom how could you use your function when you do not define any input for it?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
def addition():
    total = 0

    while True:
        value = input()

        if value == "exit":
            break
        else:
            try:
                total += int(value)
            except:
                print('Please enter in a valid integer')

    print(total)
```

EDIT

---

There are two reasons why the code isn't working properly:

First, the reason why it is failing is because you are trying to cast the word "exit" as an integer.

Second, as user2357112 pointed out, there are two *input* calls. The second input call was unintentionally skipping every other number being entered in. All you needed to do was one *input* call and set the entered value into a variable.

Comment: That's not the problem. There are two `input` calls, and the one checking for `'exit'` silently skips every second number. You've changed it to just one `input` call.

Comment: @user2357112 Interesting, I didn't realize that; thanks for pointing that out. I'll update my comments in the answer stating for that future views.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the `while` loop, without using `x` and `y`.

```
def addition():
    total = 0
    while True:
        total += int(input())
        if input() == "exit":
            break

    print(total)

addition()
```

Comment: thanks for the tip but does not solve the inconsistency

Comment: You should use `raw_input` instead, store the result and then process it. You should also catch the `ValueError` exception when the conversion to `int` fails.

Comment: @Vincent OP might be using Python 3.x in which case `input()` is as valid as `raw_input()`

Answer (score 0):

These are a few ways you can improve your code:

1. Run the loop forever and break out of it only if the user enters "exit"
2. To know when the user entered "exit" check if the input has alphabets with [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

Making the above changes:

```
def addition():
    total = 0
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if user_input.strip().isalpha() and user_input.strip() == 'exit':
            break
        total += int(user_input)

    print(total)

addition()
```

Comment: Looks like [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl). You should consider [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) instead.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for the link, I had not seen that before. But reading through that, I am not sure how I can apply it here. I would argue that `if` condition is in fact testing for pre-conditions before summing up the inputs. Could you help me understand where I am missing the point?

Comment: Ok, you know that casting an invalid string to int will raise a `ValueError`, so you could use something like `try: total += int(user_input) except ValueError: if user_input == 'exit': break`.

Comment: @Vincent But I am already ruling out string inputs in the `if`. The code will only get to the `total += int(user_input)` when it has no alphabets

Comment: I'm not saying your code doesn't work, just know that there is a more pythonic way to do it. See [this article](http://oranlooney.com/lbyl-vs-eafp/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

```
def safe_float(val):
    ''' always return a float '''
    try:
       return float(val)
    except ValueError:
       return 0.0

def getIntOrQuit():
    resp = input("Enter a number or (q)uit:")
    if resp == "Q":
       return None
    return safe_float(resp)


print( sum(iter(getIntOrQuit,None)) )
```

is another way to do what you want :P